# What prevents contestants from collaboration with a planted buyer during the sale phase?

Tags: production, flea-market-flip

I'm watching the Flea Market Flip episode "The Flipping Unicorn", where a buyer picks up all the furniture from one team's side for a hefty profit, after the team spent quite a while not making much effort to sell anything.

It may not have been a planted buyer, but the way the show framed it, it came off as fishy.

What restrictions are in place to prevent a team from sending an acquaintance in to purchase their furniture from them to grant them a potential win?

Comment: not the answer to your question but, keep in mind that these shows are edited to tell the story; it's entirely possible they edited out all the footage of them *trying* to sell because they knew there was the big all-at-once purchase coming later and wanted to build drama.

Comment: Screality Tv. Scripted reality, like jersey shore or storage wars

Comment: @KutuluMike - the duo who didn't sell were distinctly discussing their non-sales pressure technique of "sitting back and waiting for the sale to come to them".